# How can i Validate inputext with react native if someone touch input box and leave it blank(Modified)

Tags: javascript, validation, react-native, ecmascript-6

TextInput is component from react native

```
   <TextInput
     style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}
      />
```

[image]

Comment: would you not need to reference the input when you are about the submit the form and then check using regular expressions as an example based on your needs and submit the form if it passes validation?

Comment: i want this error if someone touch input box and leave it blank and i am new with react native how can i show this error and also underline with red color

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 types of validation. 1, when you press some button to login and 2 when you validate text input every time someone presses a character.
You need to save a state for the validation error message.

```
<Button onPress={() => {
  if (this.state.text.trim() === "") {
    this.setState(() => ({ nameError: "First name required."}));
  } else {
    this.setState(() => ({ nameError: null}));
  }
}} title="Login">
```

Now where you display text input, below it you need to show a text which is displayed when the `nameError` property in state is not null,

```
<TextInput style={...} onChangeText={...} value={...} />
{!!this.state.nameError && (
  <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
    {this.state.nameError}
  </Text>
)}
```

Comment: how can i handle on that case if someone touch input box and leave it blank

Comment: Hi, there are onFocus and onBlur listeners which are called when text input is in focus and blur respectively. <TextInput onFouc={} onBlur={() => this.state.text.trim()==="" && alert("Name field is required.")} />